# Call java function from python - Chaquopy

Tags: java, python, android, chaquopy

I went through Chaquopy docs and found; with Chaquopy, java and python code can be called as user wishes.

I went through example apps and found examples for either calling python from java or running Android code through python and not the other way like calling java function from python.

Is there some example available or some reference for calling java function from python?

It would be better to add such example on Github examples if not already available.

Referred Chaquopy [sample app](https://github.com/chaquo/chaquopy) on Github

Answer (score 2):

The API reference is [here](https://chaquo.com/chaquopy/doc/current/python.html), and there is a large example [here](https://github.com/chaquo/chaquopy/blob/master/app/src/main/python/chaquopy/demo/ui_demo.py).

If you have a specific problem, please ask another question and explain exactly what you're trying to do.

Comment: hello @mhsmith, i need one help, if I want to call a (Java) function (of Utils.java) from one of my python scripts, what should i do? I need some code base as reference. Thanks

Comment: @SolaimanHossain: For example code, see the links in the answer above.  If you still can't work out what to do, please create a [GitHub issue](https://github.com/chaquo/chaquopy/issues) and explain exactly what you're trying to achieve.